# Role Based Access Control (RBAC) using Firebase (on Free-tier Spark Plan) WITHOUT using Cloud Functions or Firebase Admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am using **Firebase** in a NextJS web-app which is hosted at **Firebase-Hosting** after going through a Static Site Generation (**SSG**) build. I am using Firebase Client SDK for **Firebase-Authentication** with `SignInWithGoogle` provider. I have successfully implemented the auth flow, but now I want to implement Role Based Access Control (RBAC) for some parts of Frontend (UI) as well as for Backend (**Firebase-Firestore**). I have read the related [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) and some related questions here on StackOverflow, they all suggest **Firebase Admin SDK** for attaching `Custom Claims` to users' *UIDs* to distinguish various user roles.

**Problem is:**

- I do not own any server, to use **Firebase Admin SDK** for assigning `Custom Claims` to users' *UIDs* for user roles
- I am on Spark Plan (Free Tier), with no access to **Firebase-Cloud Functions**

While using **Firebase Local Emulator Suite**, I noticed that in *Authentication emulator*, there is an option of editing user[image: Edit User option in Emulator]

Clicking this option allows me to write `Custom Claims`

[image: Custom Claims option in emultor]

But when I checked my project's authentication at the live Firebase console, this option of `Edit User` is missing there for assigning `Custom Claims`, as present in the Local Firebase-Emulator, even after upgrading to *Identity Platform*

[image: Edit User option missing in firebase console]

Bearing in mind that I have a statically generated (SSG) static site, is there any solution/workaround for implementing Role Based Access Control (RBAC) to assign various roles to my app users using **Firebase Client SDK** only, without having to use Cloud Functions or Firebase Admin SDK?

Comment: 1) Firebase Authentication doesn't have any built-in roles, nor a need for any. 2) You don't need a server to set custom claims, any trusted environment will do. For example, you could run a node script locally on your development machine to assign custom claims. 3) If you want to implement RBAC on Firestore, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#attribute-based_and_role-based_access

Comment: Pardon my obtuseness, but how should I assign a custom claim to a prospective new user who would visit my web app's URL on his own device (let's say his phone), and decide to sign-up by authenticating himself with his Google account?

Comment: You can't do anything based on the information on their own device, as that'd be a security risk. That's why you *always* need some trusted environment, but that can be your development machine, a server that you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.

Comment: @FAQi I think you've misunderstood Puf's comment. Instead of using the "custom claim" mechanism, Puf is suggesting you store a field (such as "role") in the user's profile data document. Then in your Firestore Security Rules, you would limit what values this "role" can be set to based on the updating user's own role. e.g. you could configure it so that new users can set themselves a role of "user", but only users with "admin" can promote other users to "admin".